# NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5 when parsing XML page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an XML page in Objective-C.  The full text of the error is:

> Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)"

I am attempting to parse the page like so:

```
NSURL *xmlUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"xmlpage"];
NSXMLParser *xmlDoc = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: xmlUrl];
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc]init];
```

Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you are doing. You create a NSXMLParser, but call it a doc. Which it isn't. You then create a XMLParser which is a ? Some third party API perhaps ?

I don't have my code in front of me, but basically you need to setup a NSXMLParser delegate which can receive the XML element as the parser reads them. You then need to tell the parser to start processing the XML.

Another thing to look at is to confirm that the URL is actually sourcing XML and not some other content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The URL is definitely valid XML.  Did I set up the syntax wrong?  I copied it from a tutorial; but it was a bit over my head.  My goal is to just create a parser that parses some 'xmlpage' and ultimately be able to access all of the various properties/attributes.  I do already have the XMLDelegate.h and .m files, though.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/drekka/dXml/blob/master/src/code/DCXmlParser.m which is a class I wrote. It creates a NSXMLParser in it's init, and then sets it up and starts it in the parseWithDelegate method at the bottom. The code is a little old (it's one of the first things I wrote!) but it's basically correct.

Comment: sorry but thisnt an answer